# Numbers retrieved from the API and numbers on the screen are different

Tags: google-analytics-api

I used the API to retrieve data from a property with Google Signals enabled and thresholds applied.
I can view the values on the GA4 screen, but when I use the API to retrieve the data, there is no data.
Is this because the Google Signal is enabled and the thresholds are applied, so the data cannot be retrieved?
Dimensions are listed below.

- totalUsers
- newUsers
- activeUsers
- sessions
- screenPageViews
- engagementRate
- userEngagementDuration
- conversions
- engagedSessions

If only sessions were retrieved from the API, they could be retrieved.
totalUser could not be retrieved.